# How to interpolate ruby language in a link to path

Tags: ruby, link-to

I would like to insert the type of my object in my link to. this one is not always the same so I don't want to write it in real letter.
I would like to write something like :

`link to "my mission", edit_+ mission.type.downcase + _path(mission)`

I don't even know if its possible.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `instance_eval` like:

```
link_to "my mission", instance_eval("edit_#{mission.type.downcase}_path(mission)")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

Comment: is the instance_eval really necessary here?

Comment: You can use `public_send` also.

Answer (score 0):

You might a regular html tag a little easier:

```
<a href='<%= edit_+ mission.type.downcase + _path(mission)%>'>
  mission_path
</a>
```